# Medical Insurance for Canadian visiting United States

Tags: usa, health, insurance, canadian-citizens

My girlfriend is going to be staying with me in the USA for a few months shortly. She is a Canadian citizen.

I would like to get some advice on what kind of Medical insurance (if any) we should be purchasing for her. Since we will be doing things like 4-wheeling it would be nice to be confident she is protected if something bad were to happen.

Should we purchase trip medical insurance? What does the Canadian health-care system cover?

Comment: You might be able to cover her under domestic partner clause but you'd have to check.

Comment: Do you mean under my own health insurance?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: I hope you find a way that she is covered, but in case you don't  never, ever go to the US without medical coverage. Even simple things can end up costing you huge amounts of money and a major accident can bankrupt you.

Comment: also remember that if you get extra coverage and you think you are covered check again!! I'm a canadian visiting friends in Arizona and the idiot at the insurance place forgot to add my extra week onto my original 2 week coverage and now no one can cover me as I have to return to canada to get it, something about canadian company can't sell anything to someone in the US =( hope I don't have trouble!

Comment: Possibly better advice would be to always check your policy yourself, before travelling, rather than assuming the insurance *person* got it exactly right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check her employer's medical coverage. Mine covers trips up to 21 days, others may be more generous. Also, check her credit card - if she buys the plane tickets on the card she may end up covered as a result of that.

To answer the second part of your question, what does Canadian health care provide, depends on your province - health care is a provincial thing. But to give you Ontario as an example, there is very rudimentary coverage. The [online advice from the Ontario government](http://www.health.gov.on.ca/en/public/programs/ohip/outofcountry/travellers.aspx) says things like:

> The Ontario Health Insurance Plan (OHIP) only covers emergency health
>   services at very limited rates. For example, an outpatient visit to a
>   U.S. emergency room may cost thousands of dollars for the duration of
>   your care, however OHIP will only reimburse up to a total of $50.00
>   CDN per day for this service regardless of the severity of the
>   situation. ***If you plan to travel outside of Ontario, it is strongly
>   recommended that you obtain additional private medical insurance and
>   fully understand what your policy covers.***

That emphasis, by the way, is in the original. There is also [a fact sheet](http://www.health.gov.on.ca/en/public/publications/ohip/travel.aspx) which is even gloomier. I doubt the answer will be remarkably different if she lives in another province.

Comment: Thanks Kate. Unfortunately her work does not offer medical coverage. She has a card, I will check into that.

Answer (score 2):

And if what @Kate Gregory suggested doesn't work you can always buy travel insurance from sites like:

- [HealthQuotes](http://www.healthquotes.ca/)
- [Kanetix](http://www.kanetix.ca/travel-insurance)

There is actually a lot of different sites that offer travel insurance including medical.